# COUNTING IN VBA

Tags: excel, vba, count

I have a number of clients in an excel spreadsheet (by client name), each associated with a particular item. For example

12345     1

12345     2

12345     2

23451     1

23451     3

55667     1

55667     2

89001     3

99999     1

99999     2

I need to count the number of distinctly different items for each client - in the above example, client 12345 has bought 3 items (output is 3); client 23451 has bought 2 items (output 2); client 89001 has bought one item (output 1). I'm sure it's a COUNT feature which looks to the previous column A and breaks/restarts the count if the client number changes, but I'm having a devil of a time doing it. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the SUM function instead? The COUNT function counts the amount of cells that are being used, the SUM adds up the integers within the cells.

Check out this link -> [Here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/tipsandfaqs/f/sum_autosum.htm)

Yes, or a better suggestion from David in the comments, [the SumIf function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php).

Thanks David!